# Start up issues with RAM

Tags: boot, memory

I bought 2x2gb of Munchin Radioactive memories 1600mhz, DDR3 for an Asus P5KC mobo of my girfriend's.

I'm having issues to power the machine on. When i first start the machine, there is a blank display and no BIOS code sound, i have to reset it, and then the machine asks for restoring BIOS parameters and THEN it boots to Windows and works normally.

This happens all the time. With previous memory (which i did not mix, i'm just using these 4 gb) the machine starts up fine.

Any tips?

Comment: What are the specs for the previous RAM?

Answer (score 0):

First up, boot from a [MEMTEST86+](http://www.memtest.org/) CD, and run tests on your RAM overnight. I'd expect a few issues, in which case RMA your RAM.

If you don't find any issues, it might be a case of incompatible RAM. Sure, you have bought RAM of the right spec, but it's not always as simple as that - though it ought to be! Often mobo manufacturers specifically approve particular brands/models of RAM - if you don't have such RAM you *may* find it difficult to get support from your mobo manufacturer. However, most will still help, so check out their support pages - perhaps they can help you out, or perhaps another buyer will have had problems with the same RAM.

Have you checked the mobo manual to check the spec and position of the RAM? Sometimes manufacturers insist that certain RAM configurations use particular positions or settings.

Failing that, sell your RAM and buy a different brand/model.

EDIT: I've owned plenty of ASUS kit before - they have some slow-but-well-marshalled forums - it's worth pitching your problem there, to find out if other people have had problems with your RAM or your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Before running a lengthy memtest, try booting with only one stick of RAM. If that doesn't work, try just the other. Most of the time ONE faulty card ruins the others.

If all this fails, try cleaning the RAM slots very well with some pressurized air. I've had the exact same thing happen to me before and it was due to the CPU (being very close to the RAM slots) pushing dust and particles into the slots. Give that a clean (make sure your board is off, duh) and see if it helps.

Obviously if all that fails and a memtest doesn't help you will need to RMA your RAM. This means you send it back to the manufacturer and get new sticks. This happens sometimes with technology being damaged on the way to your doorstep.

Good luck!

**EDIT:** As I mentioned above, when trying just a single stick of ram, also try each slot. In case the slot is the issue. Remove as many ***points of failure*** (keyword) as possible.